# pyspark always GC overhead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I'm studying spark but I have a question.

when I intersect a csv file by pandas it works very well but
if I use spark df it always makes error about gc overhead.

this is my code

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, concat, udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.pandas as ps
from time import time
import pandas as pd


spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataFrameExample").config("spark.executor.memory", "30g")\
    .getOrCreate()

# pandas df
drug_df = pd.read_csv(drug_data, sep='\t', index_col=0, comment='#')
drug_df.index.name="entrez:id"
dis_df = pd.read_csv(disease_data, sep='\t',index_col=0, comment='#')
dis_df.index.name="entrez:id"

#pandas df to spark df
dis_tmp_df = ps.from_pandas(dis_df)
drug_tmp_df = ps.from_pandas(drug_df)
dis_sdf = dis_tmp_df.to_spark(index_col="entrez:id")
drug_sdf = drug_tmp_df.to_spark(index_col="entrez:id")

# pyspark intersection
intersection = drug_sdf.intersect(dis_sdf)

# pandas intersection
intersection = drug_df.loc[drug_df.index.intersection(dis_df.index)]
```

why this happend? even I allocated 30g in memory?

why gc take too many memories?

and this is the my error message
[image]

and this is my padnas result
[image]